# Passing different arguments to c# dynamic library

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I'm using pythonnet in CPython, and I managed to install it so

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('Assembly')
```

did work.

In my C# code if a member

```
public void Action(double Freq, double ChannelSpace, bool RefDoubler, bool RefD2, double RCounter, int DeviceIndex)
    {... //something is done
    }
```

if I try now to do (in Python):

```
from Assembly import Class
from System import Double, Int32,Boolean
Class.Action(Double(3000), Double(10), Boolean(False), Boolean(False), Double(10), Int32(0))
```

it always complainy and says:

```
TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```

Why?

Comment: I don't know python but should these not be separate: `Boolean(False, Double(10), Int32(0))`

Comment: Almost certainly missing a `)` there.

Comment: If the method is not static then you have to use an instance of the class to call it, just like in Python.

Comment: Oh you're right of course `cls = Assembly.Class()` and `cls.Action (...)` did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the method isn't static you have to use an instance of the class to invoke it, i.e.

```
from Assembly import Class
obj = Class()
obj.Action(...)
```